# c# How get security code in textbox area?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname, htmlelements

```
<table>
```

```
            Security code: <span style="font-family:'Segoe UI Bold', 'Segoe UI Semibold', 'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue Medium', Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;color:#2a2a2a;">9949598</span>
        </td>
```

I am want code show in textbox in the windows form application area.

Below code to I am trying this in my textbox area but not success.

Please help me for this.

```
 HtmlElementCollection bColl = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
        foreach (HtmlElement bEl in bColl)
        {
            if (bEl.GetAttribute("style").Contains("Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;color:#2a2a2a"))
                txtLinkDetails.Text = bEl.OuterHtml.Split('"')[3];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go

```
if (geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("delete_3_2") != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("getelementbyid available!!!");
}
```

Checking for null generally requires checking whether the element is null, for example by `!= null`  :)

Regards